# Why is tableView cell not dynamic?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, interface-builder, word-wrap

### Update:

I have found that the problem occurs because of the date labels top constraint when removed the wrapped text becomes visible. The issue is then the date label is under the other text. Could the real problem be that the cell is not dynamically changing based on the constraints?

I am trying to make text in a UILabel to wrap (at the same time I am trying to make the cell change based on the text)

In the `.xib` I setup the cell, doing this:

```
    self.notifInfoLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    self.notifInfoLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

[image]
`sizeToFit` is called right before returning the cell in the delegate method.

```
cell.notifInfoLabel.sizeToFit()//EDIT: turns out this is not needed
    
    return cell
}
```

The configure method is called on `viewDidLoad` and right before `.reloadData()`

```
func configureTableView() {
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 82
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

Currently, the text in the label seems to wrap underneath the date label...

**How can I make it work as intended?**

Comment: “How can I make it work as intended?” What is intended? What happens instead?

Comment: intended means it "wraps (at the same time I am trying to make the cell change based on the text)", so it the notif text is too long it will wrap to the next line and everything else in the cell will adjust to take this into account, @matt let me know if you need extra info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have confusing constraints  for Auto layout engine.

- You want some space from bottom of image view if text is small , And
- you want text to dynamic in that case label should grow.

Solution is very simple.

Bottom constraint of `Imageview` change **=** to **>=** with **750** priority

Bottom constraint of `Date` change **=** to **>=**

Hope it is helpful

Comment: Do you know how I could make the profile image centered? Currently, it does not center...

Comment: @Outsider You can try to remove top constraint of image view and give centre Constraint to image view, **You May need to reset the priority to 1000** of image view bottom

Comment: @Outsider one more thing you may face constraint break for image view width and height constraint. For that **you can remove height constraint,  add aspect ratio 1:1 with 750 priority**